# Indian currency symbol (₹) in PDF Generation using apache FOP

Tags: pdf-generation, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop, xslt-3.0

I am trying to generate a PDF file which contains invoice details with amount and its currency symbol.

However when I write an Indian currency symbol (**₹**) to the XML file my output shows only **#** in the PDF file.  The same issue happens for the Japanese currency symbol too (**¥**).

MY XML :

```
<invoice-detail>
     <invoice-number>sample001</invoice-number>
     <invoice-amount>₹50,00,000</invoice-amount>
</invoice-detail>
```

MY XSL :

```
<fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" padding-top="3pt">
       <xsl:value-of select="invoice-amount"></xsl:value-of>
</fo:block>
```

we using **Apache FOP** for generating PDF file by xml and xsl file, also using **jasperreports-fonts(6.8.0)** for font styles and mapped those fonts in **fop.xconf** file.

Comment: It would help if you show us minimal settings of your fop.xconf as well. I have not been able to get the Indian currency symbol character displayed with the generic font family sans-serif but on a Windows system and with the setting `<auto-detect/>` in the fop.xconf and use of `font-family="Arial"` I get it rendered, for instance. The Japanese currency symbol seems to be less troublesome.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes you are right, i tried with auto-detect in fop.xconf file and changed my font family as Arial it worked fine in my windows system..i need to check same in server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a true type font that supports the characters in the font-family. Or alternatively, you can specify it for an individual character.

```
<fo:inline font-family="Symbol">&#8377;</fo:inline>
```

If your font is already capable of displaying the character, then use the character code instead of the character itself.

Your code should look like this instead:

```
<invoice-detail>
     <invoice-number>sample001</invoice-number>
     <invoice-amount>₹50,00,000</invoice-amount>
</invoice-detail>
```

`₹` = `&#8377;`

`¥` = `&#65509;`

https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#pdf-characters

Comment: You may be able to use the &#8377; for the Indian Rupee rather than specifying a font directly. Test -- and if not, then add the code above.

Comment: I tried with this..but same # symbol get printed in output pdf.

Comment: You may have to go with the <fo:inline> solution. You may have to add some logic for choosing the character (e.g. have a currency field rather than just the invoice amount)